# Is there a way to filter by a value in an array of strings using SQL API in Cosmos DB?

Tags: arrays, azure-cosmosdb, where-clause, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am new to SQL API. I'm trying to write queries for documents like this:

```
{
   "School" : "ABC Elementary"
   "Grades" : [
      {
          "gradeLevel" : "First",
          "subjects" : ["Drawing", "Music", "Numbers", "Words" ]
      },
      {
          "gradeLevel" : "Second",
          "subjects" : ["Art", "Music", "Numbers", "Phonetics" ]
      }
   ]
}
```

another document could be

```
{
   "School" : "DEF Elementary"
   "Grades" : [
      {
          "gradeLevel" : "First",
          "subjects" : ["Drawing", "Music", "Numbers", "Words" ]
      },
      {
          "gradeLevel" : "Second",
          "subjects" : ["Arts & Crafts", "Music", "Numbers", "Phonetics", "PE" ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm trying to write a query that will return documents that have "PE" as a subject (only one in the above example, the "DEF Elementary" school document) or "Music" (both school documents in the example).

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM c 
JOIN o IN o.Grades 
WHERE "PE" IN o.subjects
```

but that isn't returning any results. I'm not certain if this query is possible unless each subject is also an object:

```
"subjects" : [
   {"name" : "Art"}, 
   {"name" : "Music"}
]
```

If SQL API is not capable of returning results, could it be done with a stored procedure and / or UDF, while also factoring partition boundaries?

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Comment: Yes, it helped me very much! Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Use below sql:

```
SELECT c.School,c.Grades FROM c 
JOIN o IN c.Grades 
WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(o.subjects,"PE",true)
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "School": "DEF Elementary",
        "Grades": [
            {
                "gradeLevel": "First",
                "subjects": [
                    "Drawing",
                    "Music",
                    "Numbers",
                    "Words"
                ]
            },
            {
                "gradeLevel": "Second",
                "subjects": [
                    "Arts & Crafts",
                    "Music",
                    "Numbers",
                    "Phonetics",
                    "PE"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```